# Mapping a list of attributes to a linked list (timeline) in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

> Neo4j 3.5.6

I'm trying to map a list of month names to a linked list of months spanning multiple years

I created a timeline linked list based on this [post](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) using this code:

```
WITH range(2018, 2020) AS years, range(1,12) as months
FOREACH(year IN years | 
  MERGE (y:Year {year: year})
  FOREACH(month IN months | 
    CREATE (m:Month {month: month})
    MERGE (y)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(m)    
  )
)

WITH *

MATCH (year:Year)-[:HAS_MONTH]->(month)
WITH year,month
ORDER BY year.year, ID(month)
WITH collect(distinct(month)) as months, collect(distinct(year)) as years
CALL apoc.nodes.link(months, "NEXT")
CALL apoc.nodes.link(years, "NEXT")
RETURN years
```

What I would like to do is add the names of the months as a new attribute.  I originally tried doing that by modifying the query above, but it didn't quite work and it seemed like it might be more efficient to perform the task as two separate queries, so I rolled the set query off as a separate action.

This was my first attempt:

```
WITH range(1,12) AS months, ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] AS month_names
UNWIND months AS month
UNWIND month_names AS month_name
WITH month, month_name
MATCH (m:Month {month: month})
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(m, 'name', apoc.agg.nth(month_name, month-1)) YIELD node
RETURN count(*)
```

My intent was to assign in order each name to each group of months (e.g. month nodes with month = 1 has name set to "Jan"), but I got the error:

> Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError: Aggregations should not be used like this.

If I replace the apoc.agg.nth function with a string, the query works (albeit by setting every name attribute to the string)

I tried simplifying the problem to see if I could map two lists:

```
WITH range(1,12) AS months, ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"] AS month_names
UNWIND months AS month
UNWIND month_names AS month_name
WITH month, month_name
RETURN month, apoc.agg.nth(month_name, month-1) AS month_name
```

Which gives me the expected results:

```
month   month_name
1   "Jan"
2   "Feb"
3   "Mar"
4   "Apr"
5   "May"
6   "Jun"
7   "Jul"
8   "Aug"
9   "Sep"
10  "Oct"
11  "Nov"
12  "Dec"
```

But if I try to include a match statement to pull out the month nodes, it gives me every combination of month and month_name for all 36 month nodes.

Short version: I can't figure out how to properly map the month name to the month number when setting the node property, and I don't know whether it's more efficient to set that property in a single query at node creation or as a standalone query after node creation.

Answer (score 0):

This simple query should do what you want (as a separate query):

```
MATCH (m:Month)
SET m.name = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][m.month-1]
RETURN COUNT(*)
```

Alternatively, you could change the `CREATE` clause in your first query to:

```
CREATE (m:Month {
  month: month,
  name: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"][month-1]
})
```